# Disable logging of logical replication statements in Postgres 13.1

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13, logical-replication

I have a simple process that is reading logical replication messages from postgres. This process runs every second and generates a lot of messages in the postgres logs like:

```
2021-02-15 20:35:11.032 UTC [35] STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM pg_logical_slot_get_changes('lazy_cloud', NULL, NULL);
2021-02-15 20:35:11.032 UTC [35] LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at 0/167C618
2021-02-15 20:35:11.032 UTC [35] DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.
```

I've configured logging with the following settings:

```
log_min_messages=ERROR
log_statement=none
log_replication_commands=0
```

But, the logical replication logs are still produced.

Is there a setting to disable these messages? I can use sed or something like that, but would prefer a built in solution.

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: It's a custom version of decoder_raw from pg_plugins: https://github.com/pj/pg_plugins?organization=pj&organization=pj

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to disable that message short of setting

```
log_min_messages = fatal
```

in `postgresql.conf`, but that is not a smart idea, because then you'd miss out on all error messages in the log file and essentially disable logging.

Comment: Thanks, I "fixed" this by filtering out the messages.